# mysterious margin for nav dots

Tags: html, css

I have created a very simple dot navigation on my site banner **[HERE](http://codeandcode.co/demo/dots-error/main.html)**. The HTML code i have used is as follows:

```
<ul class="carousel-dots">
    <li>
        <a href=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href=""></a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
        <a href=""></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now for the `<li>` element i have the following code:

```
.banner ul.carousel-dots li {
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(../img/res/carousel-dots.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Now even though i have `margin: 0;` in my style, i get a margin between the left and right, i don't know where are these spaces coming from , i would want the dots to be touching each other , side to side. So whats causing this mysterious margin ?

Comment: It is a probels and tabs from your source code. Check view-source:http://codeandcode.co/demo/dots-error/main.html. `display: inline-block;`Read https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @0x860111 thanks genious !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## white space between inline-block elements?

The space is actually created by the "enter" between your elements.

[How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

In the question above there are a lot of different answers how to remove it.
I set the parent element font-size to 0.

```css
ul {
  font-size: 0;
}
ul.carousel-dots li {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
  /*background: url(../img/res/carousel-dots.png) 0 0 no-repeat;*/
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="carousel-dots">
  <li>
    <a href=""></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""></a>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <a href=""></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Or, for a more practical approach, [just use flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It was designed for this.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes , iam in the process of migrating to that ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the answer is a bit tricky, if you want it fixed, you have to remove the space between the `</li>` and the next `<li>`

So, this:

```
<ul class="carousel-dots">
<li>
    <a href=""></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href=""></a>
</li>
<li class="active">
    <a href=""></a>
</li>
```

Should become this:

```
<ul class="carousel-dots">
<li>
    <a href=""></a>
</li><li>
    <a href=""></a>
</li><li class="active">
    <a href=""></a>
</li>
```

The reason of this issue is the fact that when using inline-block, spaces are also considered inline characters, leaving space in between.

PS: There are also other ways to remove the space, by using word-spacing or other such things, but I find the simplest solution to be always the best, plus on html you should always try to minimize your code before shipping, so a few lines of `code` less is always better than a few more